# Eclipse Indigo doesn't run on Mountain Lion with JDK 7

Tags: java-7, eclipse-indigo, osx-mountain-lion

I've been trying to run Eclipse using the JDK 7 (tried the official 7u5 release and the developer preview 7u6) on Mountain Lion, but it seems it always use the Apple's JDK 6u33.

I tried configuring the Info.plist to look for the vm on my JDK 7 installation path, but when I check the VM Eclipse is using, it shows up the 6u33.

I do can configure the JDK on Installed JRE's on Eclipse and use it to compile and validate my Java 7 project, but I can't use Hibernate Tools to generate my entities on the database, because the Hibernate Configurations can't load the entities using the JDK 6 on a project set to Java 7.

Is anyone successfully running Eclipse Indigo on JDK 7 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion? If yes, how could I do it?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Just found a way to run Indigo on Mountain Lion on this link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58203/mountain-lion-with-java-7-only

Answer (score 0):

you can simply modify your eclipse.ini to point to JDK 7

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example

i.e. add the following 2 lines to eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've tried changing the eclipse.ini and the Info.plist, adding the -vm argument to them. It seems that JDK 7 doesn't have the capability to run applications yet, because eclipse still takes the JDK 6 to run.

Comment: P.S.: It shows up on log available in "About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration".

Comment: Just found something weird: Eclipse Juno runs on JDK 7, without even configuring eclipse.ini or Info.plist, just by taking the default JDK in Java Preferences. I'll stick with Juno for now and hope that the JBoss Tools work properly with it. And I'll accept your answer, once in some way it's right.

Answer (score 0):

It is dirty... but it works..
Trick your MAC that you have 1.6.0 though it points to Java 7

```
sudo mkdir /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk
```